# resizing partition was removed in latest version of parted

Tags: parted

I am trying to resize a partition without tampering data on it. I cant backup data in external harddisk (as I am targeting this as a script) and internet backup was not an option.

I was trying to use parted's resize command in 1.8 version. Later noticed that parted had a bug in 1.8 version for resizing fat 32 file system. Hence updated to parted 3.1 version.

Now I realized that parted 3.1 version doesnt support resize partition option.

I tried using fatresize utility too. However latest version of fatresize failed to compile against parted 3.1 as "PED_ASSERT" API of libparted has changed since 2.4.

Is there any other way I have than going back to parted less than 2.4?

Comment: You haven't specified your distribution.

Comment: By distribution u mean my OS?

Comment: Yes, the Linux distribution (Fedora/Ubuntu/SUSE/Mint etc.)

Comment: I am using a customized ARM openstack Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Install version 2.2 or 2.3-7 (max) and try that, the change came in 2.3-8.

I cannot guarantee that it will work, you are shrinking a partition without a backup, that is dangerous - important data ought to be backed up in at least two physical locations.